# Meaning of the nabla operator in the expression $\vec{u}\cdot\nabla\vec{u}$

Tags: derivatives, vector-fields

In the context of physics, I have the following equation, which is the Euler equation for a fluid:

$$\rho\bigg(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}+\vec{u}\cdot\nabla\bigg)\vec{u}=-\nabla P$$

where $\rho$ and $P$ is the density and pressure respectively (both scalars),  and $\vec{u}$ is the velocity. I want to understand what this equation means, so I am trying to write the left hand side in terms of derivatives, instead of the nabla operator, since I believe this is three equations packed into one. However, I am having trouble understanding what $\vec{u}\cdot\nabla\vec{u}$ is. As far as I know, $\nabla\vec{v}$ is a scalar. So, is the following correct?

$$\bigg(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}+\vec{u}\cdot\nabla\bigg)\vec{u}=\dfrac{\partial\vec{u}}{\partial t}+\vec{u}\cdot\nabla\vec{u}=$$

$$=\underset{vector}{\underbrace{\bigg(\dfrac{\partial u_x}{\partial t},\dfrac{\partial u_y}{\partial t},\dfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial t}\bigg)}}+\underset{vector}{\underbrace{(u_x,u_y,u_z)}}\cdot\underset{scalar}{\underbrace{\bigg(\dfrac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}\bigg)}}$$

The dot used between the vector and the scalar leads me to believe that both should be vectors and that the dot represents a scalar product between vectors, but I don't understand how.

Comment: No. $(\vec{u}\cdot \nabla)\vec{u}\not\equiv\vec{u}\cdot(\nabla\cdot \vec{u})$.   
$\nabla$ is vector which components are $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, then scalar product $(\vec{u}\cdot \nabla)$ is $\left(u_x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+u_y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}+u_z \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)$ And $(\vec{u}\cdot \nabla)\vec{u}=u_x \frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial x}+u_y \frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial y}+u_z \frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial z}$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu So, is the accepted answer here wrong? I'm completely confused now...
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160229/advection-operator

Comment: Yes, accepted answer is wrong. Commutative property holds for dot products of vectors, but not for this case because result of $\nabla\cdot \vec{u}$ is scalar field and result of $(\vec{u}\cdot \nabla)$ is operator (there is no operand right to nabla).

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu So, what  you mean is that $(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\cdot\vec{u}=\vec{u}\cdot(\nabla\cdot\vec{u})$ but $(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}\neq\vec{u}\cdot(\nabla\vec{u})$, right? And $\nabla\vec{u}$ is a 2 x 2 matrix?

Comment: Both records $(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\cdot\vec{u}$ and $\vec{u}\cdot(\nabla\cdot \vec{u})$ are not good (there was mistype in my first answer). First record should be $(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}$ (operator $(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)$ applies to $\vec{u}$), second record should be $\vec{u}(\nabla\cdot \vec{u})$ (vector is multiplied to scalar $(\nabla\cdot \vec{u})$ ). Record $\nabla\vec{u}$ can be used as synonim of $\nabla\cdot\vec{u}$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Sorry, I understood the answer that you posted, but I don't understand this. Do you mean that $(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}\neq \vec{u}(\nabla\cdot\vec{u})$?

Comment: Yes. I mean exactly this. As for Physics SE: I think question in Physics SE had another context, author of accepted answer made difference between $\nabla\vec{u}$ and $\nabla\cdot\vec{u}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}=\left(\sum_i u_i \vec{e}_i \cdot \sum_j \vec{e}_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right) \sum_k u_k\vec{e}_k$$
Using $\vec{e}_i\cdot\vec{e}_j=\delta_{ij}$:
$$(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}=\left(\sum_i u_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right) \sum_k u_k\vec{e}_k$$
Using $\frac{\partial \vec{e}_k}{\partial x_i}=0$:
$$(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}= \sum_k \vec{e}_k\left(\sum_i u_i \frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_i}\right)$$
For example, $x$ component is
$$\left((\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}\right)_x= \sum_i u_i \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x_i}=u_x\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}+u_y\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}+u_z\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial z}$$